# Triple Boot MacOS, Windows, Linux: Windows Boots over Grub

Tags: windows-10, macos, ubuntu, boot, grub

I have a cosmetic problem but would like to know the reason behind the following behavior:

Upon pressing "option" to boot my iMac2019 I can choose between the 3 operating systems. But Windows will no longer boot directly upon selecting as before installing gUbunutu. Instead, it goes to the Grub boot manager which gives me the choice between Ubuntu or Windows (also, upon selecting Ubuntu I will pass by this Grub menu).

Does anyone know what's the cause of this behavior or does anyone know how to fix this?

kind regards