# In Ubuntu Change Default Startup to MacOS

Tags: windows-10, macos, ubuntu, boot

I have installed on my iMac2019 MacOS, Windows10, and Ubuntu 22.04. After setting in MacOS Default Startup OS to MacOS I get this changed somehow by Ubuntu after having used my Ubuntu OS. Likewise, Windows10 does change the Default Startup OS.

Is there a way to tell Windows and Ubuntu to don't do that?

Comment: Asked at https://superuser.com/questions/1806066/triple-boot-macos-windows-linux-windows-boots-over-grub